# Can two USB RNDIS gadgets with the same IP connect to one computer's VNC servers?

Tags: usb, ip, vnc, android

I have two android gadgets set to USB tether mode, connecting to one  computer.

I'd like to have one gadget connect to **VNC** on `port 5900` and the other on `port 5902`.

When they're both connected, the computer shows ***two*** new ***usbX*** interfaces in `ifconfig`.

Static IPs:

**usb1** : `192.168.42.42`

**usb2** : `192.168.42.43`

At this point, with both connected only ***one*** gadget is able to connect to a VNC server on the computer at a time (and either one does fine individually).

Output of `arp -a` (with either devices attached): `192.168.42.129`.

It possible to connect both gadgets at once with the same IP as `192.168.42.129`?